# how can i use variable in findcontrol?

Tags: find, controls

first,i add gridview my page..and i creat textbox dynamically for each cell..

```
textboxarray[idm].ID = idm.ToString();
```

idm is a variable which contains textbox id.

when i want to control by if control

```
if (((TextBox)(GridView2.Rows[str].Cells[stn].FindControl(idm.ToString()))).Text != null)
                            {
                                matris[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.Rows[str].Cells[stn].Text);
                            }
```

occur an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

how can id do it?